# Where are all the Attack Pieces on Dreamy Mount Pajamaja?

Tags: mario-luigi-dream-team

When you are in the normal world and thus have a world map, all of the Attack Pieces are shown on it. However, when you are in the Dream World, there is no map, making the Attack Pieces harder to find.

I already missed Attack Pieces in previous Dreamy areas, and I don't want that to happen here.

Where are all the Attack Pieces in Dreamy Mount Pajamaja?

Answer (score 1):

There **is a map** in the Dream World! Tap the **bottom left** button on the bottom screen - the one that says "map". Using this, it should be a whole lot easier to find the pieces, by looking for icons that look like attack pieces, and unexplored areas.

If you're still having trouble, **[this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=rH_dRHSeMMM#t=112)** might help.